# new matrix[N][N] failure

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, stack-overflow

I'm having a stack overflow allocating a huge matrix on the stack (and I agree with that: it's stupid to allocate it there) and I'm writing the following code since I want to access the matrix's elements with the subscripts indices mat[x][y]

```
double (*mul1)[N][N];
mul1 = new double[N][N];
```

I'm receiving an error:

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'double (*)[1000]' to 'double(*)[1000][1000]'
```

Why can't I allocate a bidimensional array with new?

Comment: This is actually slightly different from the question someone linked as duplicate, because (I assume) N is known at compile time. You can do it with `double (*mul1)[N];` and you avoid the pointer indirection that appears in the linked question for the nested arrays. (The key is that the `*` _replaces_ one of the `[]`, and `new T[]` returns a pointer to the first element.) Or you can write `unique_ptr<double[][N]> mul1(new double[N][N]);` and get automatic cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double *mul1[N];
for (int i=0;i<N;++i)
    mul1[i] = new double[N];
```

[Representing a 2D array as a 1D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449713/representing-a-2d-array-as-a-1d-array)

[Performance of 2-dimensional array vs 1-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242705/performance-of-2-dimensional-array-vs-1-dimensional-array)

Comment: error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'double (*)[1000]' to 'double **'

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
int N = 10 ;
double** mul1 = new double*[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
   mul1[i] = new double[N];
```