# Why doesn't int** ptr point to the same address as int arr[3][3] when accessing ptr[i][j]?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586075/new-matrixnn-failure/15586169#15586169) but when I tested the following code
I got confused.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int **ptr;
        int arr[3][3];
        ptr =(int **) arr;
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<3;j++){
                        cout << &arr[i][j] << " =? ";
                        cout << &(ptr[i][j]) << endl;
                }

        }


        return 0;
}
```

But I get this ouput:

```
0x7fff5700279c =? 0
0x7fff570027a0 =? 0x4
0x7fff570027a4 =? 0x8
0x7fff570027a8 =? 0
0x7fff570027ac =? 0x4
0x7fff570027b0 =? 0x8
0x7fff570027b4 =? 0
0x7fff570027b8 =? 0x4
0x7fff570027bc =? 0x8
```

Why aren't they the same?

Comment: Because you've used an evil cast: `ptr =(int **) arr;` `ptr` needs to be declared `int (*ptr)[3];`.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515045

Comment: `int*` and `int[]` are compatible, but you made a common but incorrect generalization when you thought that meant `int**` is compatible with `int[][]`. That's the reason you had to add a cast, casts are dangerous, avoid where possible.

Comment: @john so basically you can't declare a function for higher dimensions than 1D which handles arrays with variant size ?

Comment: Right. You can look into templates, but that is essentially writing multiple functions. Or you can change your calling code to use something other than arrays (such as std::vector). That is the usual solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int **ptr` and an `int arr[3][3]` are different, since:

```
 -----------------------------------
|    C    |         Maths           |
 -----------------------------------
| ptr + 1 | ptr + sizeof(int*)      |
 -----------------------------------
| arr + 1 | arr + 3 * sizeof(int*)  |
 -----------------------------------
```

So you won't get the same results at all (moreover, `ptr` and `arr` may not have the same memory representation).

```
int (*ptr)[3] = arr;
```

will work, since only the first dimension of `arr` decays to a pointer.

Answer (score 12):

```
ptr =(int **) arr;
```

That is very bad - it involves a `reinterpret_cast` and results in undefined behaviour. The two types - an `int[3][3]` and an `int**` - are completely incompatible in terms of memory layout.

A 3-by-3 2D array is a contiguous block of memory that looks like this:

```
  0,0   0,1   0,2   1,0   1,1   1,2   2,0   2,1   2,2
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │ int │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

A pointer to pointer to `int` where each pointer points at the first element in an array looks like this:

```
┌─────┐
│     │ // The int**
└──╂──┘
   ┃
   ▼
┌─────┬─────┬┄
│     │     │   // An array of int*
└──╂──┴──╂──┴┄
   ┃     ┗━━━━━━━━━━┓
   ▼                ▼
┌─────┬─────┬┄   ┌─────┬─────┬┄
│ int │ int │    │ int │ int │    // Arrays of ints
└─────┴─────┴┄   └─────┴─────┴┄
  0,0   0,1        1,0   1,1
```

This involves two levels of indirection. The 2D array type doesn't have the array of pointers to go through. In addition, the arrays of `int`s in this `int**` case are not necessarily contiguous.

So think about when you do `ptr[0]`, for example. What is the type of the expression? Since `ptr` is an `int**`, the type of `ptr[0]` is an `int*`. However, what is *actually* at the location `ptr[0]`? Not a pointer at all! Instead, there's an array of `int`s.

Comment: @Kirilenko Thanks! [Box-drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) are the best!

Comment: Awesome boxes, comprehensive answer. +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

int** is a pointer to a pointer to int. Which means it is referring to an array of pointers. However, int[x][y] is an array of integers x by y in size. It is a single block of memory arranged into x rows of y columns (if you care to think of it that way.

To achieve what you want, you would have to collect the addresses of the columns and store them in the rows of your int** pointer.

```
int   arry[3][3];
int** ptr = malloc( sizeof(int*) * 3 );

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
   ptr[i] = arry[i];

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        printf( "%d -> %d\n", arry[i][j], ptr[i][j];

free( ptr );
```