# What is the preferred way to deal with two-dimensional arrays?

Tags: java, scala, memory-management

I'm not good with java conventions and best practices.

I need two-dimensional buffer for some big calculation involving dynamic programming and doubt if I should use one-dimensional array and map two coordinates to single, or use array of arrays and chained access by indexes.

In C I would prefer the first way, but Java is not a C and may have extra specifics that matter.

Comment: I see know problem with having an actual 2d array..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959098/efficient-implementation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-java?rq=1

Comment: and believe it or not java is also not scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need top speed, definitely use a single array (one-dimensional) and map your indices as appropriate. As I see in the thread linked to in a comment below your question, people seem to disregard the ill effects of 2d-arrays on CPU cache lines and emphasize only the number of memory lookups.

There *is* one consideration to take: if your inner arrays are large enough (1K or more, say), then the speed advantage starts fading away. If the inner arrays is smallish (like 10-50), then the difference should be noticeable.

#### EDIT

As rightfully demanded, here's my `jmh` benchmark:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class ArrayAccess
{
  static final int gapRowsize = 128, rowsize = 32, colsize = 10_000;
  static final int[][] twod = new int[colsize][],
      gap1 = new int[colsize][];
  static final int[] oned = new int[colsize*rowsize];
  static final Random r = new Random();
  static {
    for (int i = 0; i < colsize; i++) {
      twod[i] = new int[rowsize];
      gap1[i] = new int[gapRowsize];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsize*colsize; i++) oned[i] = r.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < colsize; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < rowsize; j++)
        twod[i][j] = r.nextInt();
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public int oned() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsize*colsize; i++)
      sum += oned[i];
    return sum;
  }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public int onedIndexed() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < colsize; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < rowsize; j++)
        sum += oned[ind(i,j)];
    return sum;
  }

  static int ind(int row, int col) { return rowsize*row+col; }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public int twod() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < colsize; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < rowsize; j++)
        sum += twod[i][j];
    return sum;
  }

}
```

Note the *gap* array allocation: this simulates the worst-case scenario with fragmented heap.

I see more than 5-fold advantage at `rowsize` = 32 and a still quite noticeable (25%) advantage at 1024. I also find the advantage to highly depend on the gap size, with the shown 128 being the worst case for `rowsize` = 32 (both higher and lower values diminish the advantage), and 512 the worst case for `rowsize` = 1024.

```
rowsize = 32, gapRowsize = 128

Benchmark    Mean        Units
oned         8857.400    ops/sec
twod         1697.694    ops/sec


rowsize = 1024, gapRowsize = 512

Benchmark   Mean     Units
oned        147.192  ops/sec
twod        118.275  ops/sec
```

Comment: @StefanKunze Please help yourself to it, see my edit!