# Populate char array dimension

Tags: c#, .net

I have below multidimensional char array:

```
int l = 6;
char[,] initialCharArray = new char[l, l];
```

Later in my code I build a char array (cArray) which I pretend to assign later to all dimensions of the intial char array (initailCharArray):

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(l);
  for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
   sb.append('$');

  char[] cArray = s.toString().toCharArray();
```

Now I would like to assign cArray to all dimensions but it is not working:

```
  for (int x = 0; x < l; x++) initialCharArray[x] = cArray;
```

I know in Java is possible but how I can do it using C# in an effective way?

Comment: What’s `maz`? What does “it is not working” mean?

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099266/c-sharp-assign-1-dimensional-array-to-2-dimensional-array-syntax

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, I have corrected

Comment: You'd need a jagged to do that (an array of arrays) `char[6][]` not `char[6,6]`

Comment: Also since you are using C# and not Java, I assume you know that those methods are named `ToString` and `ToCharArray` (not `toString` and `toCharArray`)

Answer (score 0):

Complet working code using jagged array:

```
int l = 6;
char[][] initialCharArray = new char[l][];

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(l);
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
  sb.Append('$');

char[] cArray = s.ToString().ToCharArray();

for (int x = 0; x < l; x++) initialCharArray[x] = cArray;
```