# 3D array (1D flat) indexing

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d, flatten

I am using a coordinate system x (width), y (height), z (Depth)

Just to clear confusion if there is any x & y are a flat plane and I am using Z as elevation.

I am going to be accessing the array millions of times per second and benchmarking shows that a 1D array using index is faster and I would like to squeeze as much efficiency as possible so that other things can use that time

For example a 2D array --> 1D array creation is just

```
Object[] oneDArray = new Object[width * height]
```

and to index the array I can just use the following.

```
Object obj = oneDArray[x + y * width]
```

I did find the following on stackoverflow but I am not entirely sure which one is correct
[How to "flatten" or "index" 3D-array in 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367770/how-to-flatten-or-index-3d-array-in-1d-array)

The "Correct" answer says to index the array do the following

```
Object[] oneDArray = new Object[width * height * depth]
Object obj = oneDArray[x + WIDTH * (y + DEPTH * z)]
```

But then another answer says that the "Correct" answer is wrong and uses the following

```
Object[] oneDArray = new Object[width * height * depth]
Object obj = oneDArray[x + HEIGHT* (y + WIDTH* z)]
```

What is the correct way to read a flattened 3D array?

Comment: For your current definitions of width, height and depth, neither variant is correct.

Comment: Has your profiling shown that this will be the major bottle neck? Because otherwise you're giving yourself a major headache for little gain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on that how you want to order your 3D data in 1D array,
if you wanted to have indexes in order: Z, Y, X then your 2x2x2 dimensioned 3D data will be stored like this:

```
index 0: [z=0,y=0,x=0]
index 1: [z=0,y=0,x=1]
index 2: [z=0,y=1,x=0]
index 3: [z=0,y=1,x=1]
index 4: [z=1,y=0,x=0]
index 5: [z=1,y=0,x=1]
index 6: [z=1,y=1,x=0]
index 7: [z=1,y=1,x=1]
```

DEPTH dimension corresponds to `z`, HEIGHT to `y` and WIDTH to `x`

The index calculation will be: `index = HEIGHT*WIDTH*z + WIDTH*y + x`.

The x is not multiplied by anything because the next x index is right after the previous one.

If you want to skip one Y row, you have to add whole row WIDTH, in this case 2, for example if you are at index 1, which has z=0,y=0 and x=1 and you add WIDTH=2 to index, you'll get index 3. Only y dimension has increased by 1.

To move from z=0 to z=1, you have to skip 4 indexes (look up at the index listing), the number is HEIGHT*WIDTH (in this example 2*2).

**Performance**

To gain speed its best to process your 3D data with z,y,x coordinates incrementing in a sequence so you don't have to recalculate the index so often. For example:

```
int z = 1, y=1, x=0;
int index = HEIGHT*WIDTH*z + WIDTH*y;
int data;

for(x=0;x<WIDTH;x++)
{
    Object obj = oneDArray[index+x];
}
```

In ideal case, all processing of data is independent from each other and you don't have to even calculate the index, just increment one index trough whole `oneDArray`. What's possible  to precompute depends on your usage.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution in Java that gives you both:

- from 3D to 1D
- from 1D to 3D

My own micro benchmark showed that 1D array is 50% faster to get/set values than through 3D array.

Below is a graphical illustration of the path I chose to traverse the 3D matrix, the cells are numbered in their traversal order:

[image: 2 Examples of 3D matrices]

Conversion functions:

```
public int to1D( int x, int y, int z ) {
    return (z * xMax * yMax) + (y * xMax) + x;
}

public int[] to3D( int idx ) {
    final int z = idx / (xMax * yMax);
    idx -= (z * xMax * yMax);
    final int y = idx / xMax;
    final int x = idx % xMax;
    return new int[]{ x, y, z };
}
```

The code above could surely be factorised to be faster, but I left it as such to make it easier to understand the 2 way conversion ;)

Answer (score 3):

use the formula `index = x*height*depth + y*depth + z` 
Sample java code illustration.

```
public class FlattenedArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int width = 2;
        int height = 3;
        int depth = 4;
        int[][][] d3 = new int[width][height][depth];
        int[] d1 = new int[width*height*depth];

        //3D Array :
        int w=0;
        for(int i=0;i<width;i++) 
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
                for(int k=0;k<depth;k++) {
                    d3[i][j][k] = ++w;
                    System.out.print(d3[i][j][k] + " ");
                }
        System.out.println();

        //1D Array :
        w=0;
        for(int i=0;i<width;i++) 
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
                for(int k=0;k<depth;k++) {
                    int index = i*height*depth + j*depth + k;
                    d1[index] = ++w;
                }

        for(int i=0;i<width*height*depth;i++) {
            System.out.print(d1[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```