# Fastest wasy to copy a 3 dimensional byte array to replace PART of another 3 dimensional byte array

Tags: c#

I have a winform desktop C# application.

I have an image of size 720x576.

The image is represented by a 3 dimensional byte array:
720x576x3.

The x3 is representing the 3 colour channels of Red, Green and Blue.

This Image is divided logically (for my purpose) into 4 regions like so:

[image]

Say I have a new byte array for Region 4 and I wish to update this 'Base' Array.

I could do it like this:

```
         for (Int16 camIndex = 0; camIndex < 4; camIndex++)
            {
                if (camsChanged[camIndex])
                {
                    Rectangle roi = Rectangle.Empty;
                    switch (camIndex)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            roi = new Rectangle(0, 0, 360, 288);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            roi = new Rectangle(360, 0, 360, 288);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            roi = new Rectangle(0, 288, 360, 288);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            roi = new Rectangle(360, 288, 360, 288);
                            break;
                    }
                    for (int x = roi.X; x < roi.X + roi.Width; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = roi.Y; y < roi.Y + roi.Height; y++)
                        {                              
                            BaseImage[x, y, 0] = NewBaseImage[x, y, 0]; //signifies Red Channel
                            BaseImage[x, y, 1] = NewBaseImage[x, y, 1]; //signifies Green Channel 
                            BaseImage[x, y, 2] = NewBaseImage[x, y, 2]; //signifies Yellow Channel
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But is there a quicker way? I looked at Buffer.BlockCopy and Array.Copy but I could not see how it could help me in this scenario as it looked to replace the entire 'Base' array?

Thanks

Comment: `memcpy` for every row, perhaps?

Comment: @Alexander Hi, thanks for your thoughts.  At least I am not missing anything obvious then which is reassuring. I can certainly give this a go and run some speed test. Thanks

Comment: This question should be tagged with C#, not C.

Comment: Are you assuming that Array.Copy isn't going to work for you because you have a 3 dimensional array?

Comment: @Ayubinator Hi, yes I was. I took a look at it but I could not see how I could replace a 'region' (in my  pictorial example). Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have `4` bitmaps of `360×288` or one bitmap of `720×576`? You talk about a `720×576×4` array which would define 16 regions of `360×288`? Also in your code you only assign 3 values instead of 4. This post is confusing to me.

Comment: @ja72 Hi, you are quite right. I need to make some alterations. Sorry, been up since 3:17am. Will adjust now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question. Now I can answer using `Buffer.BLockCopy()`. I've slaved around for a while, but I got it to work nicely. Here is the proof of concept code:

```
public enum CameraPos
{
    TopLeft = 0,
    TopRight = 1,
    BottomLeft = 2,
    BottomRight = 3
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int W=360, H=288;

        var BaseImage=new short[2*W, 2*H, 3];

        // Initialize sequential numbers so I can debug the results easier.
        short num=0;
        for (int x=0; x<2*W; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y<2*H; y++)
            {
                // num = color + 3*( y+576*x )
                BaseImage[x, y, 0]=num++;
                BaseImage[x, y, 1]=num++;
                BaseImage[x, y, 2]=num++;
            }
        }

        var NewImage=new short[2*W, 2*H, 3];

        CopySubImage(BaseImage, NewImage, CameraPos.TopRight);
        // this copied x=360..719 and y=0..287
    }

    static void CopySubImage(short[, ,] base_image, short[, ,] new_image, CameraPos cam_index)
    {
        int W=base_image.GetLength(0)/2;
        int H=base_image.GetLength(1)/2;

        int x_index=((int)cam_index%2)*W;  // either 0 or 360
        // int y_index=((int)cam_index/2)*H;  // either 0 or 288 (not needed)

        // Copy columns with Buffer.BlockCopy. Shown below are the flat array indeces.
        //
        // | 3*(0+576*0) 3*(0+576*1) .. 3*(0+576*359) | 3*(0+576*360)   .. 3*(0+576*719)   |
        // | 3*(1+576*0) 3*(1+576*1) .. 3*(1+576*359) | 3*(1+576*360)   .. 3*(1+576*719)   |
        // |     ..                           ..      |       ..               ..          |
        // | 3*(287+576*0)      ..    3*(287+576*359) | 3*(287+576*360) .. 3*(287+576*719) |
        // + ---------------------------------------- + ---------------------------------- +
        // | 3*(288+576*0)      ..    3*(288+576*359) | 3*(288+576*360) .. 3*(288+576*719) |
        // |     ..                           ..      |       ..               ..          |
        // | 3*(575+576*0)      ..    3*(575+576*359) | 3*(575+576*360) .. 3*(575+576*719) |

        for (int x=x_index; x<x_index+W; x++)
        {
            int k_start=3*(y_index+2*H*x);
            //int k_end=3*(x_index+W+720*y); (not needed)

            Buffer.BlockCopy(base_image, k_start, new_image, k_start, 3*H*sizeof(short));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't and it looks useful. But I still need all the data to be represent in a 3 dimensional array.

Comment: I have a working answer now. Try it and let us know.

Comment: Hi, just logged in. Looks like you have done a lot of work.  I will try this out and get back to you. Many Thanks!

Comment: So how much faster is it?

Comment: Hi again. It is faster but I have not done speed tests as I am drinking a bottle of Shiraz :). I will do those tests and report back but by general observation the RAM is down so I assume it is doing the work more efficiently.

Comment: Good to see you have your priorities in order. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Array.Copy eliminates the need for bounds checks on every index call (thus runs much faster). The big wrinkle here is that you're dealing with a multidimensional array. Because you're concerned with speed you should flatten to a single dimensional array. This SO question covers both flattening and indexing ([How to "flatten" or "index" 3D-array in 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367770/how-to-flatten-or-index-3d-array-in-1d-array))

I personally don't have much experience using BlockCopy but Array.Copy yields much better performance than copying each item individually.

**EDIT**

It occurred to me that you might actually be able to call Array.Copy on a multidimensional array but you have to pass the calculated index values. Unfortunately, you're four regions aren't arranged in contiguous blocks. Take a look at this simpler (2-d) example to illustrate the problem:

```
        int[,] a = new int[4,4];
        int quadrent = 1;
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
            {
                if (x < 2)
                {
                    if (y < 2)
                    {
                        quadrent = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        quadrent = 2;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (y < 2)
                    {
                        quadrent = 3;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        quadrent = 4;
                    }
                }
                a[x, y] = quadrent;
            }
        }

        int i, j;

        /* output each array element's value */
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", a[i, 0], a[i, 1], a[i, 2], a[i, 3]));
        }

        //split the line;
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Array.Copy(a, 0, a, 11, 4);

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", a[i, 0], a[i, 1], a[i, 2], a[i, 3]));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
1, 1, 2, 2
1, 1, 2, 2
3, 3, 4, 4
3, 3, 4, 4


1, 1, 2, 2
1, 1, 2, 2
3, 3, 4, 1
1, 2, 2, 4
```

So you won't be able to call the Array.Copy over the entire region but you'd be able to call it on contiguous segments of the code. The fact that you have a 3rd dimension will add to the complexity but it should be possible. This eliminates the need to flatten directly, but you'll need to still loop over sections. That being said, you should still see a measurable speed improvement.

Comment: Hi, yes i had considered that but this will be an extra process and then i need to 'unflatten' it for it to work for my purpose.