# making random.choice from a matrix of propabilities

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to make a simulator of incoming messages to output ports.
I am given the number of input ports (N) and the number of output ports (M) and a flattened matrix of probabilities of N*M (mat). I am also given the number of incoming messages as an array (in_freq).
I figured that in order to direct each message from an input port o an output one I should use numpy.random.choice, but didn't manage to make it work.

what I tried is:

```
 for k in range (N):  
       enqueue = np.random.choice(M, in_freq[k], p=[(mat[k*N:k*N+M-1])])
```

when enqueue is an array of the destinations of the messages.

But encountered the message:

> ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Comment: It's not clear why you need to make the choice from the matrix. Why can't pick a value from N and a value from M?

Comment: Your probability parameter is not 1d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

The `ValueError` that you're seeing is, as hpaulj pointed out in the comments, due to the fact that your `p` argument is wrapped in list brackets `[]`. This extra enclosing `list` makes `np.random.choice` interpret your `p` as a 2D array of shape `(1, x)` instead of a 1D array. Since your first argument to `np.random.choice` is an integer, the function expects `p` to be 1D, and so throws an error when it sees that it is not (see the [`choice` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) for complete details).

You can fix that `ValueError` by just removing the brackets around `p`:

```
enqueue = np.random.choice(M, in_freq[k], p=mat[k*N:k*N+M-1])
```

However, now your code will raise a new and different `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: a and p must have same size
```

This `ValueError` is caused by the fact that the way you're generating the row slices of your flattened NxM matrix `mat` is not correct.

## The solution

From the description in your question, it seems like what you intended was to loop over the rows of the original 2D `mat` by slicing the 1D `mat`. Here's how you can fix the slicing in your code so that you iterate over the rows of `mat` in your `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
M = 5

in_freq = np.random.randint(0, 10, N)
mat = np.random.rand(N, M)
# normalize so that each row is a probability dist
mat /= mat.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
# flatten to match OP's question
mat = mat.flat

for k in range(N):
    print((M*k, M*(k + 1)))
    enqueue = np.random.choice(M, in_freq[k], p=mat[M*k:M*(k + 1)])
```

## Testing

In order to demonstrate that the correct slices are now being generated, I added a print statement that outputs the slice indices in each iteration of the `for` loop. Here's the output from that:

```
(0, 5)
(5, 10)
(10, 15)
(15, 20)
(20, 25)
(25, 30)
(30, 35)
(35, 40)
(40, 45)
(45, 50)
```

which shows that the slices required to iterate over the rows of `mat` are indeed being generated as expected now.

## Notes about converting a 2D index to its 1D flattened equivalent

Given an array with `N` rows and `M` columns, the general formula for converting a 2D `x,y` index into its flattened 1D equivalent `i` is:

```
i = x + M*y
```

You can find a more in-depth discussion in this [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367770/how-to-flatten-or-index-3d-array-in-1d-array).