# How to send slice of a 3D array by using MPI?

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a 3D array `Foo3D` (50 x 100 x 100) in ranks 0 and 1. `Foo3D` is allocated like this:

```
int nx = 50;
int ny = 100;
int nz = 100;
typedef int nRarray[100][50];
nRarray *Foo3D;
if ((Foo3D = (nRarray *)malloc((nx*ny*nz)*sizeof(int))) == 0) {fprintf(stderr,"malloc1 Fail \n"); return 1;}
```

I assign some numbers to `Foo3D` in rank 0 and save it to a new 2D array (`Foo2D`) as:

```
if (myrank == 0) {
for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
 for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++) {

   Foo3D[0][j][k] = j + k;
   Foo2D[j][k] = Foo3D[0][j][k];
}
 } 
}
```

Now, I'm interested to send `Foo2D` to rank 1, and place it in its position in `Foo3D`. In fact, I know I can send `Foo2D` to rank 1 as:

```
if (myrank == 0)
{
 MPI_Send(Foo2D,sizeof_Foo2D,MPI_INT,1,100,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else if (myrank == 1)
{
 MPI_Recv(Foo2D,sizeof_Foo2D,MPI_INT,0,100,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

And then assign the received `Foo2D` in rank 1 to its position in `Foo3D` as:

```
if (myrank == 1)
{
for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
 for (int k = 0; k < nz; k++) {

   Foo3D[0][j][k] = Foo2D[j][k];
}
 } 
}
```

Instead of using this procedure and `Foo2D` as an intermediate variable, is it possible to send the slice of `Foo3D` in rank 0 **directly** to its equivalent position in rank 1 or not? In fact, I don't want to send the whole `Foo3D` to rank 1 because it's a really large array and I'm interested to send just a slice of it to rank 1.

Comment: you arrays must be allocated in contiguous memory, but your snippet does not show how they were declared. please upload a [MCVE] if you need more help with this.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Done.

Comment: some stuff is still missing, and this is not yet a [MCVE]. there is also likely a typo in your `else if(...)` test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the array `Foo3D` as `int[nx][ny][nz]`. Because C/C++ are *row-major* languages, the elements of the grid face represented as `Foo3D[0][j][k]` are **actually continuous** in memory.

[image: Memory Layout for i=0]

So you can simply send the face where `i=0` using:

```
if (myrank == 0) {
    MPI_Send(Foo3D, ny*nz, MPI_INT, 1, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
else if (myrank == 1){
    MPI_Recv(Foo3D, ny*nz, MPI_INT, 0, 100, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

**On the other hand**, if you want to send **non-contiguous** data **without** using a buffer ([Zero-Copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy)), you can create a custom MPI datatype that represents the data you want to copy, and send directly from the source buffer, and MPI will read the data you specified even if it is non-contiguous in memory. This can be done using [`MPI_Type_vector`](http://pages.tacc.utexas.edu/~eijkhout/pcse/html/mpi-data.html#Vectortype).

For example, if you want to send the values where `k=0`, that is, the grid face
`Foo[i][j][0]`.

[image: Memory Layout for k=0]

First, create a data type representing the face of the grid that you want to send.

[image: Diagram of MPI_Type_vector inputs]

```
// Create a data type and save its size
MPI_Datatype cubeface;
int cubefacesize;
MPI_Type_vector(nx*ny, 1, nz, MPI_INT, &cubeface);
MPI_Type_commit(&cubeface);
MPI_Type_size(cubeface, &cubefacesize);
```

Then, you can send and receive using:

```
if (myrank == 0) {
    MPI_Send(Foo3D, 1, cubeface, 1, cubefacesize, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
} else if (myrank == 1) {
    MPI_Recv(Foo3D, 1, cubeface, 0, cubefacesize, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

Comment: Your derived datatype would be correct in Fortran, but this is C here.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet You mean row and major column arrays? Cause in FORTRAN the arrays are column major but in C the arrays are row major, right?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet You are right! Thank you. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Yes, I believe this is what Gilles meant. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Aziz I think still something is not correct here... Do you flatten your 3D array by using this formula: i+j*n_{x}+k*n_{x}*n_{y}, if yes, so the XY plane is continuous not YZ plane...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer If you're defining the array as `int[nx][ny][nz]`, then the order of elements in memory is `Foo3D[0][0][0]`, `Foo3D[0][0][1]`, `Foo3D[0][0][2]`, .. etc.  Hence, the formula is `k + j*Nz + i*Nz*Ny`. This is because C/C++ are row-major.

Comment: @Aziz I don't think so. The correct formula must be: `i+j*Nx+k*Nx*Ny`. See the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16610069/10382271

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I understand the source of confusion. Your formula is correct **if** you define the array as `int[nz][ny][nx]` and access the elements as `Foo3D[k][j][i]`. But since you are using `int[nx][ny][nz]`, the mapping is done in the order `z,y,x` and not `x,y,z`. This example shows how elements are stored in memory https://godbolt.org/z/-oblH4. This is a C/C++ thing (because they're row-major), and because you are using the syntax `int[][][]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198260/discussion-between-aziz-and-alone-programmer).