# correct method of casting 3D array into 1D array

Tags: python

I found multiple [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367770/how-to-flatten-or-index-3d-array-in-1d-array) with almost the same title but none of them have a working code.

so I have the following 1D array `a`, once I reshape it to 3d array `b`, and then reshape it back to 1D array.

```
import numpy as np

depth = 2
row = 3
col = 4

a = np.arange(24)
b = a.reshape((depth, row, col))
c = np.zeros(row*col*depth)

print(a)
print(b)

index = 0

for i in range(depth):
    for j in range(row):
        for k in range(col):
            c[k+ j * row + i * (col*row)] = b[i][j][k]  # ???
            # c[k + row * (j + depth * i)] = b[i][j][k]
            # c[index] = b[i][j][k]
            # index+=1

print(c)

# [ 0.  1.  2.  4.  5.  6.  8.  9. 10. 11.  0.  0. 12. 13. 14. 16. 17. 18.
# 20. 21. 22. 23.  0.  0.]
```

I don't get `Flat[x + WIDTH * (y + DEPTH * z)] = Original[x, y, z]` in this case.

**EDIT**

I am using this code (the equivalent) in a CUDA code, so I need the loops. I am not going to use any numpy magic functions.

Comment: The input is `a = [0 ..23]`, the output `c` should look like the initial array `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the array you created uses [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) instead of column-major as you assumed

The correct way to compare is

```
depth = 2
row = 3
col = 4
a = np.arange(24)
b = a.reshape((depth, row, col))
b.strides

i,j,k = np.indices(b.shape)

assert(np.all(a[(i*row+j)*col+k] == b[i,j,k]))
```

If you want more information on how the matrix is arranged you can check
`b.strides = (48, 16, 4)`, this gives the coefficient (in bytes) of each index, i.e.g `(i*48+j*16+k*4)` is the offset of the element `b[i,j,k]`.

This is the column-major order is called Fortran order and you can get numpy to reshape assuming it by passing `order='F'`

```py
bf = a.reshape((depth, row, col), order='F')
assert(np.all(a[i + depth * (j + row * k)] == bf))
```

Then `bf` will be

```
array([[[ 0,  6, 12, 18],
        [ 2,  8, 14, 20],
        [ 4, 10, 16, 22]],

       [[ 1,  7, 13, 19],
        [ 3,  9, 15, 21],
        [ 5, 11, 17, 23]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `reshape` again to your original dimension or `flatten` the resulting array:

```
depth = 2
row = 3
col = 4
a = np.arange(24)
b = a.reshape((depth, row, col))
print(b.reshape((24,)))
print(b.flatten())
```

Output:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
```

Comment: no I need the indices, this is the trivial answer.

Comment: Please rephrase then, because you stated "The input is a = [0 ..23], the output c should look like the initial array a", this output looks like the initial array `a`