# C# Using Linq to get column from jagged array

Tags: c#, linq, jagged-arrays

How do I get elements of a column from a jagged array as a flat array using Linq ????

```
public class Matrix<T>
{
    private readonly T[][] _matrix;

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        _matrix = new T[rows][];
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            _matrix[r] = new T[cols];
        }
    }

    public T this[int x, int y]
    {
        get { return _matrix[x][y]; }
        set { _matrix[x][y] = value; }
    }

    // Given a column number return the elements
    public IEnumerable<T> this[int x]
    {
        get
        {
        }
    }
}

Matrix<double> matrix = new Matrix<double>(6,2);
matrix[0, 0] = 0;
matrix[0, 1] = 0;
matrix[1, 0] = 16.0;
matrix[1, 1] = 4.0;
matrix[2, 0] = 1.0;
matrix[2, 1] = 6.0;
matrix[3, 0] = 5.0;
matrix[3, 1] = 7.0;
matrix[4, 0] = 1.3;
matrix[4, 1] = 1.0;
matrix[5, 0] = 1.5;
matrix[5, 1] = 4.5;
```

Comment: Mmh... could you provide an example of the input data and the desired output ?

Comment: Give a declaration of the array you want to flatten

Comment: Sorry I must've forgotten ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just:

```
public IEnumerable<T> this[int x]
{
    get
    {
       return _matrix.Select(row => row[x]);
    }
}
```

Of course it's better to check if `x` is not out of the range before the LINQ query.

Anyway, given that you're working on a matrix, for more clarity you could switch to a [bidimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead of a jagged array (so no doubt about the size of the 2 dimensions).

Instead, if performance really really matters for you, keep using jagged arrays which seem to be a bit faster than bidimensional arrays  (e.g [LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468832/why-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-net-slower-than-normal-arrays), [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c)).

Comment: In my opinion this would be better: `_matrix.Where(array => array.Length > index).Select(array => array[index])`

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy: actually this control can be made before the query, because this jagged array has always the same number of columns by construction.

Comment: @digEmAll i see your point. is it because jaggeds can have mixed sizes ?

Comment: @kuzyt: yes, but it's just a matter of syntax/clarity. If performance really matters for you, jagged arrays seems to be a bit faster than multidimensional array (check my edit).

Answer (score 2):

```
var source = new int[3][] {
    Enumerable.Range(1,3).ToArray(),
    Enumerable.Range(10,5).ToArray(),
    Enumerable.Range(100,10).ToArray()
};

int index = 0;

var result = (from array in source
                from item in array
                group item by Array.IndexOf(array, item) into g
                where g.Key == index
                select g.ToArray()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from row in jagged 
    from value in row 
    where value == anyvalue 
    select value;
```

anyway why do you want to use LINQ? using a classic for it will improve the performance and make easier debugging

Comment: Your where clause works on the value, but in order to select always the same column, I think it should work on the index...

Comment: In general I would use a classic for which is faster and easier to debug. You should use LINQ to object only to improve readability as in general the classic for is much faster