# Performance difference between two implementations of the same algorithm

Tags: vb.net, performance, algorithm

I'm working on an application that will require the Levenshtein algorithm to calculate the similarity of two strings.

Along time ago I adapted a C# version (which can be easily found floating around in the internet) to VB.NET and it looks like this:

```
Public Function Levenshtein1(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
    Dim n As Integer = s1.Length
    Dim m As Integer = s2.Length

    Dim d(n, m) As Integer
    Dim cost As Integer
    Dim s1c As Char

    For i = 1 To n
        d(i, 0) = i
    Next
    For j = 1 To m
        d(0, j) = j
    Next

    For i = 1 To n
        s1c = s1(i - 1)

        For j = 1 To m
            If s1c = s2(j - 1) Then
                cost = 0
            Else
                cost = 1
            End If

            d(i, j) = Math.Min(Math.Min(d(i - 1, j) + 1, d(i, j - 1) + 1), d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)
        Next
    Next

    Return (1.0 - (d(n, m) / Math.Max(n, m))) * 100
End Function
```

Then, trying to tweak it and improve its performance, I ended with version:

```
Public Function Levenshtein2(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
    Dim n As Integer = s1.Length
    Dim m As Integer = s2.Length

    Dim d(n, m) As Integer
    Dim s1c As Char
    Dim cost As Integer

    For i = 1 To n
        d(i, 0) = i
        s1c = s1(i - 1)

        For j = 1 To m
            d(0, j) = j

            If s1c = s2(j - 1) Then
                cost = 0
            Else
                cost = 1
            End If

            d(i, j) = Math.Min(Math.Min(d(i - 1, j) + 1, d(i, j - 1) + 1), d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)
        Next
    Next

    Return (1.0 - (d(n, m) / Math.Max(n, m))) * 100
End Function
```

Basically, I thought that the array of distances d(,) could be initialized inside of the main for cycles, instead of requiring two initial (and additional) cycles. I really thought this would be a huge improvement... unfortunately, not only does not improve over the original, it actually runs slower!

I have already tried to analyze both versions by looking at the generated IL code but I just can't understand it.

So, I was hoping that someone could shed some light on this issue and explain why the second version (even when it has fewer for cycles) runs slower than the original?

NOTE: The time difference is about 0.15 nano seconds. This don't look like much but when you have to check thousands of millions of strings... the difference becomes quite notable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
 For i = 1 To n
        d(i, 0) = i
        s1c = s1(i - 1)

        For j = 1 To m
            d(0, j) = j 'THIS LINE HERE
```

You were just initializing this array at the beginning, but now you are initializing it *n* times. There is a cost involved with accessing memory in an array like this, and you are doing it an extra *n* times now. You could change the line to say: `If i = 1 Then d(0, j) = j`. However, in my tests, you still basically end up with a slightly slower version than the original. And that again makes sense. You're performing this if statement n*m times. Again there is some cost. Moving it out like it is in the original version is a lot cheaper It ends up being O(n). Since the overall algorithm is O(n*m), any step you can move out into an O(n) step is going to be a win.

Comment: How did I miss that!?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I just moved the initialization of the rows outside of the inner for cycle and now the second version of the algorithm is about 40% faster that the original -- so, once again, thank you!

(I'm mad at myself for not seeing that!)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the following line:

```
d(i, j) = Math.Min(Math.Min(d(i - 1, j) + 1, d(i, j - 1) + 1), d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)
```

as follows:

```
tmp = Math.Min(d(i - 1, j), d(i, j - 1)) + 1
d(i, j) = Math.Min(tmp, d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)
```

It this way you avoid one summation

Further more you can place the last "min" comparison inside the if part and avoid assigning cost:

```
tmp = Math.Min(d(i - 1, j), d(i, j - 1)) + 1
If s1c = s2(j - 1) Then
   d(i, j) = Math.Min(tmp, d(i - 1, j - 1))
Else
   d(i, j) = Math.Min(tmp, d(i - 1, j - 1)+1)
End If
```

So you save a summation when s1c = s2(j - 1)

Answer (score 0):

Not the direct answer to your question, but for faster performance you should consider either using a jagged array (array of arrays) instead of a multidimensional array. [What are the differences between a multidimensional array and an array of arrays in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c) and [Why are multi-dimensional arrays in .NET slower than normal arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468832/why-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-net-slower-than-normal-arrays)

You will see that the jagged array has a code size of 7 as opposed to 10 with multidimensional arrays.

The code below is uses a jagged array, single dimensional array

```
Public Function Levenshtein3(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
    Dim n As Integer = s1.Length
    Dim m As Integer = s2.Length

    Dim d()() As Integer = New Integer(n)() {}
    Dim cost As Integer
    Dim s1c As Char

    For i = 0 To n
        d(i) = New Integer(m) {}
    Next

    For j = 1 To m
        d(0)(j) = j
    Next

    For i = 1 To n
        d(i)(0) = i
        s1c = s1(i - 1)

        For j = 1 To m
            If s1c = s2(j - 1) Then
                cost = 0
            Else
                cost = 1
            End If

            d(i)(j) = Math.Min(Math.Min(d(i - 1)(j) + 1, d(i)(j - 1) + 1), d(i - 1)(j - 1) + cost)
        Next
    Next

    Return (1.0 - (d(n)(m) / Math.Max(n, m))) * 100
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Seph.
I will give it a try but I'm afraid that the for cycle to initialize the second dimension of the array will take away any improvements the jagged arrays could provide.

Comment: It is definitely an improvement. About 10 - 15 milliseconds less than version 2 of the algorithm.