# bool [,] - What does this syntax mean in c#?

Tags: c#

I found in legacy code following line:

```
protected bool[,] PixelsChecked;
```

What does `[,]` mean here?

Comment: Two-dimensional array. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a two-dimensional array.

In .NET you can have two types of arrays that aren't single dimension:

1. Multidimensional arrays:

   ```
   int[,] a;    // 2 dimensions
   int[,,] b;   // 3 dimensions, and so on
   ```
2. Jagged arrays (arrays of arrays):

   ```
   int[][] a;   // an array of arrays of ints
   int[][][] a; // an array of arrays of arrays of ints
   ```

In both cases you need to initialize the variable before using it though.

Usage is also different, in the first case:

```
int value = a[1, 2]; // note the comma, and single pair of brackets
```

In the second case, you need to address each array separately:

```
int value = a[1][2]; // the first [1] will return an array, and then you take
                     // the 3rd element (0-based) of that
```

Also remember that you can initialize a multidimensional array in just one statement:

```
int[,] a = new int[10, 20];
```

whereas a single statement for a jagged array will create a single array full of null-references:

```
int[][] a = new int[10][];
```

You will also need to initialize all the elements of that array to their corresponding array references, here's a quick way to do that with LINQ in one statement:

```
int[][] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(new int[20]).ToArray();
// 10 x 20
```

Also see the [MSDN Page on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more information.

---

Fun fact: The JITter produces faster code for accessing jagged arrays than it does for multidimensional arrays, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468832/why-are-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-net-slower-than-normal-arrays) for more information.

Answer (score 8):

The `[,]` is a 2-dimensional array.

You can initialize it like this:

```
protected bool[,] PixelsChecked = new bool[Width, Height];
```

This is how you access it:

```
bool leftTop = PixelsChecked[0, 0];
```

It is basically a rectangle with values, and you can access them with `[x,y]`.

You could also create 3- and more-dimensional arrays with

```
protected bool[,,] Cube = new bool[5,5,5];

protected bool[,,,] _4dimensional = new bool[10,10,10,10];
```

Answer (score 5):

It is the syntax of *[Multidimensional Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)*

> Arrays can have more than one dimension.

In this case, it is two-dimensional array. An array can have many dimensions. Multidimensional arrays are available using a special syntax in C#.

For syntax usage, if you want to declare *n-diamensional array*, you shoud use comma `n-1` times.

When you use `bool[,] PixelsChecked` it is declaring two-dimensional array called `PixelsChecked` and their elements typed as `boolean`.

Example;

```
bool[,] PixelsChecked = new bool[2,2];

PixelsChecked[0, 0] = true;
PixelsChecked[0, 1] = false;
PixelsChecked[1, 0] = true;
PixelsChecked[1, 1] = false;
```

Remember, you need to initialize the array before using it.

**For example**, two-dimensional arrays model a plane while three-dimensional arrays model a cube or other structure.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [two dimensional array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), basicly a *2D* grid of boolean values.

To create one you can do this

```
protected bool[,] PixelsChecked = new bool[Width, Height];
```

You could even make a 3rd dimension

```
protected bool[,,] PixelsChecked = new bool[Width, Height, Length];
```

If you want to get or set a certain coordinate

```
bool Value  = PixelsChecked[X,Y];
```

You can do alot with arrays, and there are many types. You can find a nice tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array).

Comment: Or even a fourth. Or fifth. Or sixth. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

`bool[,]` is a two dimensional array of `bool`s.

Basically, instead of having the array like this:

```
true, false, false, true, false, true, etc.
```

It's kind of structured like this:

```
true, false, false, true, false, true, etc.
true, false, false, true, false, true, etc.
true, false, false, true, false, true, etc.
true, false, false, true, false, true, etc.
true, false, false, true, false, true, etc.
true, false, false, true, false, true, etc.
etc.
```

And so you can access, let's say the second item down and the third one right, like this:

```
arrayName[1,2];
```

There's other ways to do this, like to make an array of arrays, but this keeps a constant length, and is better.