# What are the differences between using int[][] and int[,]?

Tags: c#, .net, multidimensional-array

Coming from a perl background, I have always defined a 2D array using `int[][]`. I know you can use `int[,]` instead so what are the differences?

Comment: Here are some thoughts in terms of performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168897/whats-better-in-regards-to-performance-type-or-type

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The difference here is that the first sample, int[][] creates a [jagged array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx), while the second creates a [rectangular array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) (of dimension 2).  In a jagged array each "column" can be of a different size.  In a true multidimensional array, each "column" (in a dimension) is the same size.  For more complete information see the [Array section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx) of the [C# Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

[Here's a good comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c/597744)

Basically int[][] is a "jagged" array, it looks like this:

```
[] -> [1, 2, 3]
[] -> [1, 2]
[] -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

While int[,] is a multidimentional array which always has the same width and height:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4
 5, 6, 7, 8
 9, 1, 2, 3]
```

Each have their uses depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Jagged--each 'row' can have different 'column' lengths.  Multidimensional--each 'row' has the same 'column' length.

Answer (score 9):

int[][] is an array of arrays or "jagged" array: you can use this when you want different sizes in the second dimension. For example, the first sub array can have 5 elements and the second can have 42.

int[,] is a two dimensional array: The second dimension is the same through out the array. With int[7, 42] the second dimension is 42 for all 7 lines.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth.

Answer (score 4):

int[][] is a jagged array, where int[,] is a two dimensional array.

plainly

```
var a = int[][]
```

allows you do have an array like this:

```
a[0] = new int[2];
a[1] = new int[5];
```

where as with int[,] you must always have the second portion of the array be the same:

```
var a = int[2,2];

a[0,0]
a[0,1]
a[1,0]
a[1,1]
```

you can't have a[2,2];

Answer (score 3):

int[][] is called an **array of arrays**, it can have arbitrary length for each row.

int[,] is called **rectangular array**, where all the rows have the same length. it Can be simulated by the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand the difference is to look at two ways to create an nxn matrix:

```
const int n = 8, m = 8;

int[,] matrix1 = new int[n,m];

int[][] matrix2 = new int[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix2.Length; i++) { matrix2[i] = new int[m]; }

matrix1[1,1] = matrix2[2][2];
```

As you can see the second one is a bit more involved because you need the for-loop to fully create it. It is often called a jagged array because the 2nd order arrays do not need to be all of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider about a jagged array is that you are allocating non-contiguous chunks of memory. This is a good thing if you have a large array of large objects. I've seen SomeThing[n,n] create StackOverflow issues, but SomeThing[n][n] be ok.

Also, if an object gets > 85,000 bytes it goes to the LOH (Large Object Heap).
[.NET Collections and the Large Object Heap (LOH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698147/net-collections-and-the-large-object-heap-loh)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/arrays.aspx)'s an excellent article about arrays, covering this topic very well.

Answer (score 0):

you can see int[][] as to (int[])[]
(int[]) is a object