# Multidimensional arrays in Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, arrays, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

In C# there are 2 ways to create mutlidimensional arrays.

```
int[,] array1 = new int[32,32];

int[][] array2 = new int[32][];
for(int i=0;i<32;i++) array2[i] = new int[32];
```

I know that the first method creates a 1-dimensional array internally, and that the second method creates an array of arrays (slower access).

However in Java, there is no such thing as [,], and I see multidimensional arrays declared like this:

```
int[][] array3 = new int[32][32];
```

Since such syntax is illegal in C#, and Java has no `int[,]`, I'm wondering if this is equivilant to `array1`? Or is it still an array of arrays?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168897/whats-better-in-regards-to-performance-type-or-type

Comment: No, in c# there is one way to create a multidimensional array. And another to create a *jagged* array. They are two different things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are incorrect; jagged (nested) arrays are faster.  (the CLR is optimized for them)

Java does not support true multi-dimensional arrays; that's a jagged array.
The Java syntax automatically creates all of the inner arrays; in C#, that would need a separate loop.

Comment: Nested arrays are fundamentally slower than true multi-dimensional arrays.  There is a level of indirection for each level of nesting (an extra pointer to follow), and in most cases suboptimal memory locality.

Comment: @rlibby: You're right that they're slower than 1d arrays.  However, .Net 2d arrays are less efficient.  (Note that I haven't measured that)

Comment: I just did a quick benchmark, and in C# it looks like iterating through a 2D array (e.g. `int[x, y]`) takes roughly twice as long as iterating through a same-size 1D array. Good thing 18 months of Moore's Law fixes this. :) I did not compare 2D arrays with jagged arrays.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks, I didn't know .NET's multi-dimensional array implementation was so idiotic.  It takes a special kind of stupid to make single memory reference perform worse than recursively following a chain of memory references, but I guess they managed it.  Why did they even bother including multidimensional arrays if they weren't going to implement them right to ensure they perform well?

Comment: @rlibby: There are two types of arrays in the CLR: *vectors* (which always zero-based and single-dimensional) and *arrays* (which are potentially multi-dimensional and potentially don't have a zero base). I *suspect* that it's the additional "it might not have a zero base" arithmetic that makes the difference here. Just a guess though.

Comment: Maybe there is a reason that Java doesn't implement 2D arrays, if they are slower than jagged arrays.

Comment: @Hannesh: They're slower in .Net's implementation.  They're not intrinsically slower.  The reason they're slower/not support is that they're not used much.

Comment: This is blatant misinformation. Jagged arrays are ALWAYS slower due to the way they are allocated, and the extra JMPs in memory caused be this.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer: Yes, but the .Net implementation for multi-dimensional arrays is much slower, negating that benefit.

Answer (score 10):

It's still an array of arrays. It's just that in C# you'd have to create each subarray in a loop. So this Java:

```
// Java
int[][] array3 = new int[32][32];
```

is equivalent to this C#:

```
// C#
int[][] array3 = new int[32][];
for (int i = 0; i < array3.Length; i++)
{
    array3[i] = new int[32];
}
```

(As Slaks says, jagged arrays are generally faster in .NET than rectangular arrays. They're less efficient in terms of memory though.)

Answer (score 7):

Because people were concerned about the performance of multi-dimension vs staggered arrays in .NET, I implemented a few tests and benchmarked the results on 8k by 8k elements:

The tests were:

1. Multi-dimensional 2D array
2. Multi-dimensional with indices backwards (y first)
3. Multi-dimensional with GetLength(x) instead of integer bound
4. Staggered with backwards indicies
5. Staggered
6. One dimensional (size x size) with multiplication in index
7. One dimensional with increment index

And the results:

```
one <> Elapsed Time: 0.543558s
two <> Elapsed Time: 0.8911516s
three <> Elapsed Time: 0.8908123s
four <> Elapsed Time: 1.1367238s
five <> Elapsed Time: 0.3039648s
six <> Elapsed Time: 0.8110969s
seven <> Elapsed Time: 0.2629394s
```

For fun I ran them on the WP7 emulator as well, and got similar numbers.

Code of the test function is [here](http://pastie.org/1742436).

Comment: Your sixth test is incorrect (according to your test description), as you use x + y*size as offset and thereby jumping around in the array. The offset should of course be x*size + y.

Answer (score 3):

In Java you are declaring an array of arrays.

You can see this by the following code:

```
int[][] arrOfArr = new int[5][];
arrOfArr[0] = new int[5];
arrOfArr[1] = new int[1];
arrOfArr[2] = new int[9];
...
```

`int[][] arr = new int[3][3];` is just shorthand for:

```
int[][] arr = new int[3][];
arr[0] = new int[3];
arr[1] = new int[3];
arr[2] = new int[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

I was translating some Java code to C# - here is how I did the Jagged array

```
    //Java
    private static int grad3[][] = {{1,1,0},{-1,1,0},{1,-1,0},{-1,-1,0},{1,0,1},{-1,0,1},{1,0,-1},{-1,0,-1},{0,1,1},{0,-1,1},{0,1,-1},{0,-1,-1}};

    //C#
    private static int[,] grad3setup = { { 1, 1, 0 }, { -1, 1, 0 }, { 1, -1, 0 }, { -1, -1, 0 }, { 1, 0, 1 }, { -1, 0, 1 }, { 1, 0, -1 }, { -1, 0, -1 }, 
                                  { 0, 1, 1 }, { 0, -1, 1 }, { 0, 1, -1 }, { 0, -1, -1 } };

    private static int[][] grad3
    {
        get
        {
            int[][] grad3 = new int[12][];
            for (int i = 0; i < grad3.Length; i++)
            {
                grad3[i] = new int[3] { grad3setup[i, 0], grad3setup[i, 1], grad3setup[i, 2] };
            }
            return grad3;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an array of arrays with the same performance tradeoffs as in C#.
If you know that your array of arrays is not going to be jagged, then you can wrap it in a class to get 2-d indexing on a 1-d backing array.