# What does it mean when an integer is declared like this?

Tags: java, int, declaration

I was doing a Tetris tutorial online, and noticed that there is an integer declared like this

```
int[][][] blah;
```

Why does the integer have those 3 brackets?

Comment: An `Integer` is not an `int` they are different types.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a three-dimensional array.

Each set of brackets corresponds to an axis.  Retrieving a value within the three-dimensional space looks something like this:

```
int value = blah[x][y][z];
```

**Further Reading**
[Multi-Dimensional Arrays in Java](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html)

Comment: Despite the 9 current up-votes, I have to ask is this really a three-dimensional array? As far as I can tell from the language specification, Java doesn't appear to have multi-dimensional array support, just support for one-dimensional arrays whose elements can be arrays. As are far as I can tell there is no restriction for member arrays to have a common length, so I say calling this an n-dimensional array is doubly misleading. I would call this an array of arrays of arrays, and add that it could be jagged. By programmatically ensuring it is not jagged, it can mimic a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

It means its a three dimensional array. It can hold the values like:

```
[
 [1,2]  [4,5]
 [2,3], [6,7], 
]
```

At above, each values are integer.

`[1,2]` is an array.

```
[1,2] 
[2,3]
```

is a 2d array.

Answer (score 2):

It is a 3-dimensional array as what has been said earlier.

You might want to start slow and understand what an array is before going into 3 dimensional. An array is declared as either one of the following ways. It can be used to hold a set of values of the same type (same type as in int, string and so on) instead of having to declare individual variables for each value.

int[] myArray = new int[5];

or

int[] myArray = {1,5,7,1,2};

Answer (score 1):

It is a jagged array of integers - An array of arrays of arrays.

Comment: calling it "jagged" is misleading

Comment: Why is that? I thought n-dimensional arrays in Java are *not* bound to be rectangular are they? [caveat: my Java knowledge isn't great]. Another answers have compared the declaration to a matrix, which is more misleading since matrices are usually rectangular.

Comment: yes, they are bound to be rectangular and are of fixed length unless reinitialized.

Comment: Oh. Quick search showed this: http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/arrays2.html Is this rubbish?

Comment: According to this, arrays in Java seem to be jagged: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html and the language spec isn't particularly clear, but looks like they are jagged: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html.

Comment: This answer also claims Java arrays are jagged: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313832/multidimensional-arrays-in-java-and-c-sharp?rq=1. Anyone have a definitive source?

Comment: Incidentally, the C# language has both jagged (declaration looks like Java) and rectangular (declaration looks like [,,] for a 3D array) arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's 3 dimensional array declaration. Such declarations are given because a[5] means something different in different dimensional arrays.So its a declaration to read the references properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's a three-dimensional matrix of integers.