# Jagged Java arrays of int

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

I understand that `x` is a jagged array in

```
int x[][] = {{0,1,2,3,4},{0,1,2},{0,1,2,3}};
```

But given an array `a` like

```
int a[] = {10,3,47,4,8};
```

is `a` a jagged array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Overall CS Answer**

The term "jagged" (I've also seen "ragged") array refers to [a multi-dimension array (>1) where each element is an array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). Thus

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
```

Is not a jagged array, but

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7}};
```

Is. However, counterintuitively,

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8}};
```

is also a jagged array, even though it "looks even" if you draw it out:

```
int[][] a = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8}
};
```

This is because other coding languages (such as c#) distinguish between multi-dimensional arrays and jagged arrays. In those languages, "jagged" is not a description of the current structure of the array in question, but what type of object it is entirely. [See the difference between the two here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays)

**The Java Answer**

Unlike other languages, Java only allows for single arrays of a given type. Thus the type `int[][]` really is "an array of `int[]`". So [Java doesn't support true multi-dimensional arrays, it only has jagged arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313832/multidimensional-arrays-in-java-and-c-sharp)

Because of this, the term "jagged" array takes on a different meaning in conventional java-speak. As all arrays of dimension > 1 are truly jagged, the term "jagged" comes to mean an array of dimension > 1 whose sub arrays of differing length.Thus the following array is "jagged" because the first and second sub-arrays are of unequal length:

```
int[][] a = {{1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7}}
```

As this is equivalent to:

```
{
    {1, 2, 3, 4}, //Length 4
    {5, 6, 7} //Length 3
}
```

This array would also be considered jagged:

```
{
    {1, 2, 3, 4}, //Length 4
    {11, 12, 13, 14}, //Length 4
    {21, 22, 23, 24}, //Length 4
    {31, 32, 33, 34}, //Length 4
    {5, 6, 7} //Length 3
}
```

Even though the following is a jagged array in the technical sense, it would not conventionally be referred to as such:

```
int[][] a = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8}
}
```

Similarly, because "jagged"ness requires two sub-arrays to be of unequal length, a 1-d Array can't be jagged as it has no sub-arrays to compare.

Answer (score 4):

An array of one dimension can't be jagged, since a jagged array is an array of arrays that are of multiple lengths (as in your first example).

```
int a[] = {10,3,47,4,8};
```

is not a jagged array. The Wikipedia entry on [Jagged array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) says (in part)

> a jagged array, also known as a ragged array, is a type of multidimensional array data structure whose elements consist of one-dimensional arrays, hence it is an "array of arrays".